# Purefix Kieren Pro

Tags: bottom-bracket, sram, fixed-gear

TL;DR

FRAME: Kieren Pro (68mm BB)

1. Which BB is suitable for this frame? (want to use SRAM s100 crank)
2. If BB must be Truativ 108 or 113mm, how do adjust chainline?

Thanks for your time and efforts in advance,

Cheers, Tom

Comment: Why would you go powerspline? There's only one crank option you can do: Sram S100/S150. You'd be much better off just buying a regular old square taper BB and whatever square taper crankset fits your budget.

Comment: Second, there are a lot of questions here -- you're probably going to want to have a bike shop prep a new frameset (at least to face the BB and what not). May as well have them put in the BB while they're at it. And you could format your question to be less wall of text.

Comment: If you could edit it down from a chatty wall of text into one or even possibly two questions, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have heavily edited the original question.  @Batman 1. My Uncle recently passed away and left bike stuff: including an SRAM s100 crank. 2. Bike shops in Germany are really expensive ;) so I want to do as much as possible myself.

Comment: Even if they're expensive, I doubt that they're going to charge you 400 USD+ to do this, which is what the tools you need to prep a frame cost in the US. Or even buying all the tools you need if you don't prep the frame will likely outrun the cost of shop labor. If you want to do things yourself, get the bike shop to install the headset and BB. The rest of the stuff can go on with hex keys and an adjustable wrench.

Comment: @Batman thanks for the advice. Luckily there are several bakeshops in the area. Competition is good.